# Unable to use localizable strings

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to follow all instructions I have found in previous questions in term of localizing the application.

I Have succeeded in localizing `storybaord` when strings were generated. Now I am trying to prepare `.strings` file in order to use them in my `swift` files.

what I did:

1. new -> file -> strings file
2. Create localization of at least 2 languages on the previously created `.strings` file
3. I have put values in (polish)

`"HELLO_WORLD" = "Dzień dobry!";`

and in (english)

`"HELLO_WORLD" = "Hello world!";`

4. I have created `string extension` as follows:

> ```
> extension String {
>     var localized: String {
>         return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
>     }
> }
> ```

5. I am trying to show the value like:

`helloworldLabel.text = "HELLO_WORLD".localized

but everything I gets is the same result. In hello world label I see `"HELLO_WORLD"`

can anyone give me a hint what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the `.strings` file? It must be set to `Localizable.strings` otherwise you have to specify `tableName`.